# Converting floats to and displaying Binary Numbers in C

Tags: c, binary, hex

So I'm just diving into C during my first few days of classes. My professor proposed a question/ more of a challenge for us so I thought I'd propose it here.

```
float x,y,z;
x = 0.0;
y = 1.0;
z = -2.5;
```

He wanted us to display these numbers in binary and hexadecimal without using `%x` etc. He also hinted to use a union:

```
union U {
float y;
unsigned z;
};
```

Thank you for your time in advance. I'm just looking for help/ an explanation on how to develop such conversion.

Comment: As far as `unsigned int` has the same size of `float`...

Comment: Well, language lawyer would say the professor is committing a crime...

Comment: Hmm, so you ask **us** to do **your** challenge? Do we get the exam then?

Comment: Ok, so the `union` is just a hint for getting the float marshaled into an integer. Now take a paper and see how you would convert an integer to base-2 or base-16 and then try to code this.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35367414/2410359) will convert any object to binary.  It does not use `"%x"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way, not violating the *strict aliasing* rule would be to alias the float with a `char` array, which is allowed by the C standard.

```
union U {
  float y;
  char c[sizeof (float)];
};
```

This way you will be able to access the individual `float y;` bytes using the `c` array, and convert them into binary/hex using the very simple algorithm that can be easily found around (I will leave it up to you, as it is your assignment).

Comment: `unsigned char` has portability advantages over `char` as, rarely, `char` may have trap values.  Further, a `char` that is _signed_ , slightly complicates conversion to hex/binary display.

Comment: @chux I was considering writing `unsigned` as it has advantages with converting based as well. But decided to leave it out to reduce the noise..