# Format Specifier for fpos_t type variable?

Tags: c, file

Here I just want to see the content of variable `pos` ; so what type of format specifier have to used for that ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    FILE *fileptr = fopen("sample.txt", "r+");
    fpos_t pos;
    int val = fgetpos(fileptr, &pos);
}
```

Comment: is `fpos_t` a scalar or aggregate?

Comment: Maybe you want to use [`ftell`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/ftell) instead?

Comment: To print _any_ object, you may find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35367414/2410359) useful.

Answer (score 5):

`fpos_t` is defined in the C Standard as :

> `fpos_t`
>
> which is a complete object type other than an array type capable of recording all the information needed to specify uniquely every position within a file.

This type is not necessarily scalar, it could be defined as a `struct` with multiple members. There is no `printf` format to output it in a readable fashion.  Some systems may need to perform complex tasks to handle text files, *not every computer is a PC*.

If you are interested in the implementation, you could dump its contents as hex bytes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fileptr = fopen("sample.txt", "r+");
    fpos_t pos;

    if (fileptr && fgetpos(fileptr, &pos) == 0) {
        printf("contents of pos: ");
        for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(pos); i++) {
            printf("%02X", ((unsigned char *)&pos)[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

On many modern systems, you will get `0000000000000000` because a 64 bit integer is sufficient for all information needed to represent the offset into the file, but you should not rely on this.

Answer (score 4):

`fpos_t` is *intentionally* an opaque structure.

Furthermore, the C standard doesn't define a way of inspecting its contents (there's no `toString()` nonsense that you see in other languages like Java).

So if you want a portable solution then you're out of luck.

If it's for debugging on a particular platform, then you might be able to figure out its contents (quite often it contains an integral type specifying little more than a byte count), and output appropriately.