# how to print float as hex bytes format in C?

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

I wanted to see the float value 3.14159265 in IEEE754 format representation. So wrote this test code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
int i;
float a = 3.141592654;

printf("a = %f\n", a);

// print test 1
printf("test 1 : a = %x\n", a);
printf("test 1 2nd time : a = %x\n", a);

// print test 2
char *pt = (char *)&a;
printf("test 2 :\n");
for(i=0;i<4;i++){
    printf("%x ", (char)(*pt++));
}
printf("\n");
}
```

When I run it, several times, it shows like this :

```
ckim@stph45:~/test5] test
a = 3.141593
test 1 : a = e0cd2000
test 1 2nd time : a = e0cd2000
test 2 :
ffffffdb f 49 40 
ckim@stph45:~/test5] test
a = 3.141593
test 1 : a = 520db000
test 1 2nd time : a = 520db000
test 2 :
ffffffdb f 49 40 
ckim@stph45:~/test5] test
a = 3.141593
test 1 : a = 3b373000
test 1 2nd time : a = 3b373000
test 2 :
ffffffdb f 49 40 
ckim@stph45:~/test5] test
a = 3.141593
test 1 : a = 18a6d000
test 1 2nd time : a = 18a6d000
test 2 :
ffffffdb f 49 40
```

First question is : when using printf with %x, I expected to see 40490fdb which is 3.14159265 in IEEE754 format. But the value changes everytime I run it as you can see. What's wrong with this here? Maybe I'm missing something very basic.

Anoother question is, when I use character pointer and print the hex values as in test 2 above, how can I print 'db' instead of 'fffffdb'? (the value is shown sign extened). I think I've done these things before but can't remember it now. (My machine is little endian so LSB is shown first.)

Comment: [Hex-float output is `%a`, not `%x`.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)

Comment: What you're doing here is undefined behavior.

Comment: In the *"print test 2"* code, use `unsigned char`, loop from 3 to 0, and print with `%02x` and you'll get what you wanted.

Comment: @user2357112 when I use %a, I get `a = 0x1.921fb6p+1`. I want to see the value in hex.

Comment: @user3386109 Ok, I know it's little endian so printing it from 3 downto 0 will show it correct. After chaning to unsigned char, I get `40 49 0f db`. One solved! thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are missing is how to obtain a valid *look* at the bits that make up the IEEE-754 single-precision floating point number as its equivalent `unsigned int` representation in memory. To do that while avoiding violating the *strict aliasing* rule (type punning pointers), you can use a `union` between `float` and `unsigned` (or better `uint32_t` for exact width type), e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void) {

    float pi = (float)M_PI;
    union {
        float f;
        uint32_t u;
    } f2u = { .f = pi };

    printf ("pi : %f\n   : 0x%" PRIx32 "\n", pi, f2u.u);

    return 0;
}
```

Using `unsigned` instead of `uint32_t` and understanding it may not be 32-bits on all hardware, the standard *format string* will suffice, e.g. `printf ("pi : %f\n   : 0x%0x\n", pi, f2u.u);`. (you can drop the include of `stdint.h` and `inttypes.h` in that case)

**Example Use/Output**

This will allow you to get the hex representation of the bits that make up the floating-point number when interpreted as an unsigned type:

```
$ ./bin/float_hex
pi : 3.141593
   : 0x40490fdb
```

Comment: Fine, adding a "char pt[4];" within the union also solves the char issue.

Comment: Very true - you get to make up the 32-bits any way you like as long as you stay within the rules. Only issue with `char [4]` is you are then left to cast to `unsigned` (or `uint32_t`) at some later point (keyboard rant deleted) `:)`

Comment: Thanks, using union is one method. I put my answer using `*(unsigned int*)&a` and that is the type of simple method I wanted.

Comment: @Chan Kim: Your "simple method" is broken.

Comment: @ChanKim you are *type punning* a pointer which is not allowed in C (aside from `char`). Didn't you notice the **warnings** the compiler generated? You are violating Sections 6.5 (6) & (7) of the C11 Standard.

Comment: Ok, though my compiler doesn't complain about usnig pointer type casting.. I learned this things are deemed bad pracice and we should use reinterpret cast. and learned about using union in this case. Thanks.

Comment: @ChanKim: There's no reinterpret_cast in C. C++ is a different language with different rules.

Comment: @chux `float a = 3.141592654; *(unsigned int*)&a` in the comment (6th above)

Answer (score 3):

To be clear, OP's code did not fail due to "strict aliasing rule".

[You can use `char*` for aliasing instead of your system's word. The rules allow an exception for `char*`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/99010/2410359)

Code failed as `"%x"` expects an `unsigned` and code passed a `float`.  This is *undefined behavior* (UB).  As FP values are sometimes passed in a different manner than integers, this is not surprising.

```
float a = 3.141592654;   
printf("test 1 : a = %x\n", a); // bad code
```

---

OP's later code was *almost* right.  Just needs to use the size of the object and `hh` in the specifier to only print the the value without its signed extension.

The order to print depends on endian-ness of the `float`.  Using a union still is not endian correct as endian of of a `float` and an `int` may differ - though that is uncommon.

```
char *pt = (char *)&a;
//for(i=0;i<4;i++){
for(i=0;i<sizeof a;i++){
  //printf("%x ", (char)(*pt++));
  printf("%02hhx ", *pt++);
}
```

Additional issues exist for rare platforms that have more than 8 bits to a `char`.

---

The easy alternative is to use `"%a"` [@user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45228925/how-to-print-float-in-hex-format-in-c/45246555#comment77423799_45228925) which will print the mantissa/significand in hexadecimal and the exponent in decimal powers-of-2.

---

To covert any object to a "hex" string, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35367414/2410359) code serves as an example to convert any object into a "binary" string.

Answer (score 2):

Use conversion specifier `%a` for hexfloat output.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer I was looking for is like this.

```
float a = 3.141592654;
printf("test 1 2nd time : a = %x\n", *(unsigned int*)&a);
```

Then I get

```
test 1 2nd time : a = 40490fdb
```

Comment: No. `*(unsigned int*)&a` - that's a strict aliasing violation that is not guaranteed to work. The behavior is undefined. If you want to reinterpret memory - use a union as @David C. Rankin suggested.