# Difference between writing an integer in a HEX from a real

Tags: c, floating-point, hex

I was given a task at the university, there is a number and I need to display it in HEX as it is presented on the computer. I wrote a program for translating signed integers. And I also found a real number entry in HEX. But it is different from the usual.

For integers i use: `printf("%#X", d);`

For reals i use: `printf("%#lX", r);`

If i input `12`, first prints: `0xC`

If i input `12.0`, second prints: `0x4028000000000000`

Can you explain what the difference and how it's calculate?

Comment: The `%x` format is for *integers*, not for floating point values. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: The difference is that `12` is an integer and `12.0` is a floating-point number whose binary representation follows [IEEE 754](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).

Comment: “ 0x4028000000000000” is a hexadecimal representation of the bits that encode 12 in the IEEE-754 binary64 format. It was printed because, although you used `printf` incorrectly, your C implementation happened to access those bits and format them for display. This is **not** the way you should display the representation of floating-point numbers.

Comment: With this following your previous question, it seems you are trying to print floating-point numbers in some hexadecimal format. But we do not know which. Saying it is “HEX” is not sufficiently informative. Numbers like 6+7/16+13/256 can be written in hexadecimal such as 6.7D, where the notation is the same as we use for decimal numbers except the base is 16 instead of ten. Or we can use IEEE-754 binary64 to encode the number in a special format of 64 bits, and then we can display those bits using hexadecimal. If you want help displaying the number, you must tell us which of these you want.

Comment: To print in hexadecimal the IEEE-754 binary64 encoding of a `double` named `x`, given that your C implementation uses that format for `double`, include the headers `<inttypes.h>`, `<stdio.h>`, `<stdint.h>`, and `<string.h>` and use `uint64_t u; memcpy(&u, &x, sizeof u); printf("%0x016" PRIx64 "\n", u);`.

Comment: @sam To convert the encoding of any object to hex can be done with a modification of [To convert any variable/object to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35367414/2410359) which employs binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Printing `double` value `r` using format `%#lX` actually has undefined behavior.

You have been lucky to get the 64-bits that represent the value `12.0` as a `double`, unless `r` has type `unsigned long` and was initialized from the value `12.0` this way:

```
unsigned long r;
double d = 12.0;
memcpy(&r, &d, sizeof r);
printf("%#lX", r);
```

But type `unsigned long` does not have 64-bits on all platforms, indeed it does not on the 32-bit intel ABI. You should use the type `uint64_t` from `<stdint.h>` and the conversion format from `<inttypes.h>`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int x = 12;
    printf("int: %#X  [", x);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof x; i++) {
        printf(" %02X", ((unsigned char *)&x)[i]);
    }
    printf(" ]\n");

    double d = 12.0;
    uint64_t r;
    memcpy(&r, &d, sizeof r);
    printf("double: %#"PRIX64" [", r);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof d; i++) {
        printf(" %02X", ((unsigned char *)&d)[i]);
    }
    printf(" ]\n");
    printf("sign bit: %d\n", (int)(r >> 63));
    printf("exponent: %d\n", (int)((r >> 52) & 2047));
    unsigned long long mantissa = r & ((1ULL << 52) - 1);
    printf("mantissa: %#llX, %.17f\n",
           mantissa, 1 + (double)mantissa / (1ULL << 52));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
int: 0XC  [ 0C 00 00 00 ]
double: 0X4028000000000000 [ 00 00 00 00 00 00 28 40 ]
sign bit: 0
exponent: 1026
mantissa: 0X8000000000000, 1.50000000000000000
```

As explained in the article [Double-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), this representation corresponds to a positive number with value 1.5*2<sup>1026-1023</sup>, ie: 1.5*8 = 12.0.

Answer (score 2):

The `X` format specifier expects an `int` or `unsigned int` argument.  With the `l` modifier it expects a `long` or `unsigned long int` argument.  If you call it with anything else (such as a `double`) you get undefined behavior.

If you want to print a hex float (with uppercase letters), use `%A` format, which for 12.0 will print `0X1.8P+3` -- 1½×2<sup>3</sup>

Comment: I got confused. Because in my internet research I found [sites](https://gregstoll.com/~gregstoll/floattohex/). It translates in the same way as this code. Your solution works, but in my task it is written to print 4 integers in HEX, which are a representation of this number. In my opinion, 0x1P + 0 is not quite what you need, or am I mistaken?

Comment: That site shows the conversion between bits and IEEE754 float representation, which may or may not be what your computer uses (most do these daya).

Comment: @sam Do you want to print the _value_ or the _encoding_ of the number?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica **encoding** of the number

Answer (score 0):

To produce the *encoding* of a number in hex is a simple memory dump.

The process is not so different among types.

---

The below passes the address of the object and its size to form a string for printing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>

//                                    .... compound literal ....................
#define VAR_TO_STR_HEX(x) obj_to_hex((char [(sizeof(x)*CHAR_BIT + 3)/4 + 1]){""}, &(x), sizeof (x))

char *obj_to_hex(char *dest, void *object, size_t osize) {
  const unsigned char *p = (const unsigned char *) object;
  p += osize;
  char *s = dest;
  while (osize-- > 0) {
    p--;
    unsigned i = (CHAR_BIT + 3)/4;
    while (i-- > 0) {
      unsigned digit = (*p >> (i*4)) & 15;
      *s++ = "0123456789ABCDEF"[digit];
    }
  }
  *s = '\0';
  return dest;
}

int main(void) {
  double d = 12.0;
  int i = 12;
  printf("double %s\tint %s\n", VAR_TO_STR_HEX(d), VAR_TO_STR_HEX(i) );
  d = -d;
  i = -i;
  printf("double %s\tint %s\n", VAR_TO_STR_HEX(d), VAR_TO_STR_HEX(i) );
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
double 4028000000000000 int 0000000C
double C028000000000000 int FFFFFFF4
```

With more complex objects, the output may include padding bits/bytes and the output is sensitive to endian.